# html - ul does not go back to vertical

Tags: html, css

I have this simple menu with submenu.

```
<div id="menu_footer_bg">
    <div id="menu_line"></div>
    <ul id="menu_footer">
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Works</a>
            <ul>    
                <li><a href="">Electroacoustic</a></li> 
                <li><a href="">Instrumental</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Projects</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and a simple css.

```
#menu_footer_bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: calc(100% - 50px);
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.99;      
    background-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
}

ul#menu_footer {
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 18%;
    margin-top: 1%;
}

ul#menu_footer li {
    display: inline;
}

ul#menu_footer a { 
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}

ul#menu_footer a:hover {
    background-color: orange;
}

ul#menu_footer li ul { 
    clear:both;
    position:absolute;  
    background-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
    display:none; 
    margin-bottom:-20px;
} 

ul#menu_footer li:hover ul { 
    display:block; 
    bottom: 100%;
}

ul#menu_footer li ul li {
    clear:both;
    border-style:none;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

I would like the menu to be horizontal and the submenu to be vertical.
Reading here and there I thought that this code was right - adding "display:inline" within the "li" tag of the menu.

But now, also the submenu is horizontal and I don't know how to rool back to vertical.

Answer (score 1):

Read about `>` ([Direct Child](https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/)) css selector. Your styles for `li` are applying to all children but we need only for direct children of `#menu_footer_bg`

```css
#menu_footer_bg {
    position: fixed;
    top: calc(100% - 50px);
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0.99;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
}

ul#menu_footer {
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 18%;
    margin-top: 1%;
}

ul#menu_footer > li {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
}

ul#menu_footer a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}

ul#menu_footer a:hover {
    background-color: orange;
}

ul#menu_footer li ul { 
    position:absolute;  
    background-color: rgb(20, 20, 20);
    display:none; 
    left: 0;
    bottom: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

ul#menu_footer li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu_footer_bg">
    <div id="menu_line"></div>
    <ul id="menu_footer">
        <li><a href="">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Works</a>
            <ul>    
                <li><a href="">Electroacoustic</a></li> 
                <li><a href="">Instrumental</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Projects</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `CSS`

```
ul#menu_footer li ul li{
    display: block;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xqbgmcvs/)**

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to your code

```
 ul#menu_footer li ul li {
clear:both;
border-style:none;
padding: 20px;
display:block; 
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/adit_999/6tuc1rqz/